# How i store ex chat bot conversations in dynamo-db

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, dynamodb-queries

I want to store lex conversation into dynamodb through lambda function, but I am not able to store data into dynamodb .here are the following step for creating conversational lex bot.
1. create a chatbot with intent 
2. create lambda function for lambda response in cloud watch

```
var dbhandler = require("./dbhandler");


exports.handler = async (event,context,callback) => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(event))
    var intent = event.currentIntent.name;

    dbhandler.putchatbotDetails(intent,function(err,data){
        if(err){
            context.fail(err);
        }else{
            var response = {
              "sessionAttributes": {
                 "name":  event.currentIntent.slots.name,
                 "phone": event.currentIntent.slots.phone,
                  "test": event.currentIntent.slots.test,
                  "email": event.currentIntent.slots.email,
                  "location": event.currentIntent.slots.location,
                  "college": event.currentIntent.slots.college,
                  "year": event.currentIntent.slots.year,
                  "time": event.currentIntent.slots.time,


        },   
        "dialogAction": {     
        "type": "Close",
        "fulfillmentState": "Fulfilled",
        "message": {       
           "contentType": "PlainText",
           "content": data.Item.Data
        },    
    }
};
    callback(null,response);
        }


    });
};
```

3. create dbhandler fille that store lex conversastion into dynamodb

```
/**
 * Copyright 2010-2019 Amazon.com, Inc. or its affiliates. All Rights Reserved.
 *
 * This file is licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License").
 * You may not use this file except in compliance with the License. A copy of
 * the License is located at
 *
 * http://aws.amazon.com/apache2.0/
 *
 * This file is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR
 * CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the
 * specific language governing permissions and limitations under the License.
*/
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");

AWS.config.update({
  region: "us-east-1"
});

var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

var table = "chatbotdata";
var putchatbotDetails = (intent ,callback)=>{

var params = {
    TableName: table,
    Key:{
        "intent" : "current"

    }
};

docClient.put(params, function(err, data) {
  callback(err,data);
});
};

module.exports ={
    putchatbotDetails
};
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: response not getting by lambda function